Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper-react-native-plugin:0.93.0
I'm encountering an issue while building my React Native project. The build fails with the following error message:
`  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper-react-native-plugin:0.93.0.
Required by:
project :app   `
I’ve tried cleaning the Gradle cache and rebuilding the project with ./gradlew clean.

verify that you have the following line in your
android\app\build.grade file :
implementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-react-native-plugin:0.93.0'
f it’s missing, add it to the dependencies section.

I've added the following line to the dependencies section of my android/app/build.gradle file to include the Flipper React Native plugin:
implementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-react-native-plugin:0.93.0'
However, I'm still facing the same issues.

add the dependency not to add the line
